# Getting a stronger induction principle in Coq

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

Assume the following:

```
Inductive bin : Set := Z | O.

Fixpoint fib (n : nat) : list bin :=
  match n with
    | 0   => [Z]
    | S k => match k with
               | 0    => [O]
               | S k' => fib k' ++ fib k
             end
  end.
```

I would like to show:

```
Theorem fib_first : forall n,
    Nat.Even n -> n > 3 -> exists w, fib n = Z :: w.
```

However, by performing `induction` on `n`, I get a really useless inductive
hypothesis fixing `n`, stating that `IH : Nat.Even n -> n > 3 -> exists w : list bin, fib n = Z :: w`.

What I would ideally have is the following: `IH : forall n : nat, Nat.Even n -> n > 3 -> exists w : list bin, fib n = Z :: w`. Naturally I cannot assume the original proposition, but it feels like I need to prove something stronger perhaps?

My idea for the inductive reasoning would be made possible by expanding `F n = F n-2 . F n-1`, we know `F n-2` is even iff `F n` is even, and since neither of `F n-2` or `F n-1` is empty, we can show the substring is shorter, therefore sufficient for the inductive hypothesis - how does one express this in Coq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to unfold the definition of `Nat.Even` and do induction on `n / 2` instead of `n`:

```
Theorem fib_first : forall n,
  Nat.Even n -> exists w, fib n = Z :: w.
Proof.
intros n [m ->].
induction m as [|m IH].
- now exists nil.
- rewrite <- mult_n_Sm, plus_comm.
  generalize (2 * m) IH. clear m IH. simpl.
  intros n [w ->].
  simpl. eauto.
Qed.
```

Note that your `n > 3` hypothesis is not actually needed.

Comment: I can see why now that you've pointed it out - however figuring it out is an entirely different matter :).